# Meteor upgrade to 1.6.1.1 generates a MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: meteor

I recently upgraded meteor from 1.6.1 to 1.6.1.1 and started getting the following warning:

```
Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

The problem is when I tried to deploy on heroku, I got javascript heap out of memory error after the above warning.

I added TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="--max_old_space_size=4096" and the deploy worked but took around 25 min.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you attach listeners / emit events? As you can see there is a Memory Leak detected which is a nice feature of recent node versions. Is your deployment the same slow if you resolve the memory leak?